# bigrquery error: BigQuery API has not been used in project

Tags: r, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, bigrquery

I'm trying to connect bigquery to R in a Jupyter notebook. The notebook is on Google Vertex as a managed workbook. I followed the documentation that Google released on how to connect using R, but I keep running into the error below. I try following the link given and it tells me access denied. The issue is that I've enabled the Big Query API, Notebooks API, Vertex Ai API, BigQuery Connection API, and BigQuery Data Transfer API. As far as IAM permissions, I am a BigQuery Admin Vertex AI Admin, and BigQuery connection Admin. I have triple checked that I am in the appropriate project and I have the resourcemanager.projects.get general permission. I'm not sure where I am going wrong, but I keep getting this error every time. I have tried looking in the documentation for bigrquery and I still can't figure out the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Error in `signal_reason()`:
! BigQuery API has not been used in project XXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/bigquery.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry. [accessNotConfigured]
Traceback:

1. bq_project_query(billing, sql)
2. bq_perform_query(query, billing = x, destination_table = destination_table,
   .     ...)
3. bq_post(url, body = bq_body(body, ...), query = list(fields = "jobReference"))
4. process_request(req)
5. bq_check_response(status, type, content)
6. signal_reason(json$error$errors[[1L]]$reason, json$error$message)
7. rlang::abort(message, class = paste0("bigrquery_", reason))
8. signal_abort(cnd, .file)

Comment: Could you please check that BigQuery is activated in the project by open the google cloud shell and enter `bq query "select 1"`  . Does in your  Jupyter notebook the native BigQuery work by using the `%%bigquery` magic tag? For python (and also R) I use a service account for query data.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I have confirmed that big query is activated. I tried using the %%bigquery magic tag. It works when I use it with a python kernel, but not R.